# Can Xamarin Test Cloud run tests against web app in mobile browser?

Tags: xamarin, appium, xamarin-test-cloud

We are developing a mobile web app and we would like to test it on various versions of Safari and Android browsers. Does Xamarin Test Cloud support tests that run Safari/Android browser, fire up a URL and run test cases?

Comment: You can use Appium to test iOS's Safari on Test Cloud/Mobile Center, but right now your tests would need to be written in Java. Appium support was announced at Connect 2016 : https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-test-cloud-announcements-at-microsoft-connect/

Comment: @SushiHangover while your approach may be possible, automating multiple app processes is currently unsupported in Test Cloud, and thus could lead to unexpected behavior. Source: https://github.com/xamarinhq/test-cloud-appium-java-extensions#4-current-limitations

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to automate applications that you don't have the APK or IPA files for. For this reason, you would not be able to automate the Safari or Android browsers applications. This is also further complicated by Android devices browsers in general because you cannot guarantee a certain browser will be on device. There are at least 10 types of internet browsers available to Android devices, Chrome because the standard only recently.